# Duplicate tags? [spring-rabbit] and [spring-rabbitmq]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) and [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) appear to have the same meaning, so presumably they should be merged?

I'm not 100% sure what is the better name.  It looks like "spring-rabbit" is the official name of the Spring RabbitMQ library (see https://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/, and note that the Maven artifact is called "spring-rabbit").  On the other hand, it is RabbitMQ functionality in Spring, so from that standpoint "spring-rabbitmq" makes some sense.

Comment: There's also a [spring-amqp] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 12/30/2020, [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) has been made a synonym of [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit), per [Retag [spring-rabbitmq] to [spring-rabbit]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404136/retag-spring-rabbitmq-to-spring-rabbit#404136).