# Retag [spring-rabbitmq] to [spring-rabbit]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) and [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) tags refer to the exact same thing.  This was [brought up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332899/duplicate-tags-spring-rabbit-and-spring-rabbitmq) (but did not generate much discussion) four years ago. The status quo has not changed in the intervening time.

This exact same merger [was suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391176/1108305) to positive community reaction a year ago in a rejected request to burninate the [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) tag.

> I would suggest to keep [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) separate, and make [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) as a synonym of [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit). Don't burninate anything.

These two tags should therefore be made synonyms.

Per the [Spring AMQP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) documentation, the official name of the RabbitMQ implementation is "spring-rabbit", so it seems [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) should be the primary tag, with [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) being the synonym.

> The project consists of two parts; spring-amqp is the base abstraction, and spring-rabbit is the RabbitMQ implementation.

A comment on the discussion also brought up the [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) tag.  While I strongly suspect this can be merged since Spring AMQP seems to just have the RabbitMQ implementation, this likely warrants some discussion before proceeding with that tag merge.

I do not have a score of 5 in the tag, so I cannot suggest the synonym.  I am therefore requesting someone with sufficient privileges to make [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) a synonym for [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) (with [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) being the primary tag).